# find a bounded set of real numbers with countably many limit points.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

*Find a bounded set of real numbers with countably many limit points.*

This is a question from Rudin's real analysis. I was wondering if "countably many" includes finite? Or does it have to be countably infinite?

If it includes finite, then I could just find a set with one limit point, ie.

$$\{\; 1 / n\; |\; n = 1, 2, 3, 4, \dots\;\}$$ limit point being zero.

However, if it is the case that I have to find a bounded set of real numbers with countably infinite limit points, I am stumped. Is that even possible?

Comment: Just want to point out that, since Rudin's books was written a few decades ago, a couple of his terminologies bear different meanings today. His "countable" is our "infinite and countable" (our "countable" is his "at most countable"). He also uses "neighbourhood" instead of "open ball". Nowadays "neighbourhood" has a more general definition.

Answer (score 3):

You correctly constructed a set with *one* limit point, $0$. Similarly, you can construct a set with the limit point $1$. The union of the two is then a set with *two* limit points.

Now, if a union of $n$ such sets has $n$ limit points, how would you create a set with countably infinite number of points?

Once you solve that question, you need to also bound your set. For that, let me just give you a hint that $[0,2] = [0,1]\cup [1,\frac32]\cup[\frac32,\frac34]\cup\dots$

Comment: Edit: so they do mean countably infinite right

Comment: would {1/n} U {1/2 + 1/n} U 1{1/3 + 1/n} U ....U {1/m + 1/n} for n = 1,2,3,4,...work? it would be bounded between (0, 1.5) and have as many limit points as there are positive integers

Comment: But you have to be carefull with the original argument, as a countable union of set with one limit points may be a set with an uncountable number of limits points.

Comment: @Tryss True, that's why I said the limit point should be $1$, just to keep in disjoint from the original.

Comment: @mac5 The example you stated is risky. How do you know, for example, that you didn't construct additional limit points?

Comment: if u did the limit points as 0, 1, 2, 3, .... then they would be disjoint but the set would not be bounded. I did the fractions since they tend to zero and would give us a bound.

Comment: @mac5 Yes, I know they would not be bounded, that's why I have you another hint. Look at the last sentence of my answer. It is not obvious that in your (obviously bounded) example, there are only countably many limit points.

Answer (score 0):

The set

$$\left\{ \frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{k+1} \mid (n,k) \in \Bbb N^2 \right\}$$

has $\{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n+1} \mid n\in \Bbb N\}$ as its limits points

Comment: what is N^2 signify? is it the set of all pairs (x,y) with x y being natural numbers?

Comment: @mac5 : yes, it's an usual notation

Comment: that makes sense. so 1/2 ^n makes limit points if we hold n and vary k, giving us 1/2 1/4 1/6... but if we hold k and vary n, then we get 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1,5. since one is included within the other, we only need to write the 1/k+1. is that right?

Comment: yes. And each point is isolated, so it's the only limits points (if you add 0)